# Confusion about the bounds for solids of revolution

Tags: calculus, solid-of-revolution

> Use the reduction formula for the integral:
> $$\displaystyle I_{a,n}= \int_{0}^{1} u^ne^{au} du, a\in\mathbb{R} ,a\neq0,n=0,1,2,\dots $$
> to calculate the volume of the solid of revolution obtained by revolving the region between the graph of the function $x=e^{\sqrt[3]{y}}$ and the y-axis, above the interval $[0,1]$ about

> $a)$ The line $x=-1$.

> $b)$ The line $y=-1$.

$\textbf{MY ATTEMPT}$:

The reduction formula was given to me. It's just:

$I_{a,0}=\frac{1}{a}(e^{a}-1)$

I'm confused about the "above the interval $[0,1]$". Is that $x$ or $y$? How would you know?

If it's $x$ I can't see how this is possible since the graph has an vertical asymptote at $x=0$ meaning that the area "under" it is infinite.

Second, I'm not if I should use the washer method or the shell method to do this. I did plot this and it LOOKS like this is a shell, but I am not sure...

[image]

For part a, it definitely looks like a shell and for part b, it looks like a washer, but I am not sure.

Can someone help me set up the integrals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, that is volume around $x=-1$ axis, using disk method, we have

$$V_1=\pi\int_0^1 \left(e^{\sqrt[3]{y}}-(-1)\right)^2\;dy-\pi\int_0^1 \left(0-(-1)\right)^2\; dy$$

[image]

for the second one around $y=-1$ axis, using shell method, we have

$$V_2=2\pi\int_0^1 (y-(-1))e^{\sqrt[3]{y}}\;dy$$

[image]

Comment: For $V_1$, did you mean to square the 2nd integral? Not that the answer will change but...

Comment: Yes of course! I fix that

Comment: Feel free to ask for any clarification